# Squeeze/spread histogram to set its percentiles values

Tags: python, image, opencv, histogram, distribution

I want to equalize an image by setting its channels(RGB) histogram percentile values to: 

25P - 63.75

50P(median) - 127.5 

75P - 191.25

The idea is to first shift all the histogram so the median will be set on 127.5 and then spread/squeeze the histogram so the 25/75 percentiles will be set while maintaining the histogram shape as much as possible.

I tried to implement this, and while I do get the percentiles values I wanted - the shape  of the histogram changes drastically and always looks like 3 Gaussian distribution(see in the image).

```
UPPER_BOUND = 255.0
LOWER_BOUND = 0.0
MEDIAN = UPPER_BOUND/2
P25 = UPPER_BOUND/4
P75 = 3*P25

def range_transfer(channel, old_min, old_max, new_min, new_max):
   new_channel = channel.copy()
   old_range = (old_max - old_min)
   if old_range == 0:
      if new_max == P25:
          new_channel[:] = new_max
      else:
          new_channel[:] = new_min
   else:
      new_range = (new_max - new_min)
      new_channel = (((channel - old_min) * new_range) / old_range) + new_min
   return new_channel

def equalize_channel(channel):
   ch_med = np.median(channel)
   shift_med = MEDIAN - ch_med
   new_channel = channel + shift_med

   ch_p25 = np.percentile(new_channel,25)
   ch_p75 = np.percentile(new_channel,75)
   new_channel[new_channel <= ch_p25] = range_transfer(new_channel, np.min(new_channel), ch_p25, 
                                        LOWER_BOUND, P25)[new_channel <= ch_p25]
   new_channel[new_channel >= ch_p75] = range_transfer(new_channel, ch_p75, np.max(new_channel), P75, 
                                        UPPER_BOUND)[new_channel >= ch_p75]
   return new_channel
```

[image]

Can you please help me with this?